# Conversion of string to char in c++

Tags: c++, dictionary, data-structures, hash, hashtable

I am trying to build a spell check validator using Hash Table. I have list of words in a text file. I want to imported them to program and entered them into Hash Table using seperate chaining. Now, I want to run the program and I have these two errors. Can anyone help me with this?

> at line 30-- no matching function for call to
>   'std::__cxx11::basic_string::push_back(std::__cxx11::string&)'
>
> at line 40-- no match for 'operator==' (operand types are
>   '__gnu_cxx::__alloc_traits, char>::value_type'
>   {aka 'char'} and 'std::__cxx11::string' {aka
>   'std::__cxx11::basic_string'})

I know it's simple mistake of converting str to char but I couldn't figure out how to do without changing the rest of the program.

I would like to have a simple solution which doesnot change the existing code.
If it is not possible please tell me how to proceed.

```
#include<iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstring>
#include <fstream>


std::string hashTable[27];
int hashTableSize = 27;
#define MAX_LEN 27
using namespace std;


int hashFunc(std::string s)
{
    // A simple hashing, no collision handled
    int sum=0,index=0;
    for(std::string::size_type i=0; i < s.length(); i++)
    {
        sum += s[i];
    }
    index = sum % MAX_LEN;
    return index;
}

void insert(std::string s)
{
    // Compute the index using Hash Function
    int index = hashFunc(s);
    // Insert the element in the linked list at the particular index
    hashTable[index].push_back(s);
    }

void search(string s)
{
    //Compute the index by using the hash function
    int index = hashFunc(s);
    //Search the linked list at that specific index
    for(int i = 0;i < hashTable[index].size();i++)
    {
        if(hashTable[index][i] == s)
        {
            cout << s << " is found!" << endl;
            return;
        }
    }
    cout << s << " is not found!" << endl;
}
int main(){


    //opening text file
    std::ifstream inFile;
    inFile.open("un.txt");

    // If text file doesnot exist or not included in root folder.
    if(inFile.fail()) {

        std::cerr << "Error opening file"<< std::endl ;

        exit(1);
    }

    //if text file exists.
    std::string wordsinfile;
    std::string words[100];
    int count=0,i=0;
    std::string str;


    // writing words from text file into Array.
    while( !inFile.eof()) {
        inFile >> wordsinfile;
        words[i]=wordsinfile;
        count++;
        i++;
    }

    for (i=0;i<100;i++){
        std::cout<< words[i]<<std::endl;
    }


    for(i=0;i<=23;i++) {
        insert(words[i]);
    }


    int choice;
    string z;
    string y;
    while(1) {

        cout << "Enter choice. 1) Insert\n 2) Search\n 3) Exit\n";
        cin >> choice;
        switch (choice) {
            case 1:
                cin>>y;
                insert(y);
                break;
            case 2:

                cin>>z;
                search(z);
                break;
            case 3:
                exit(0);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

***My txt file had 38 different words and size of hash table is 27***

Comment: `hashTable[index].push_back(s);` you can't call `push_back` on a string to push another string into it. When you get a "no matching function for call" kind of error, check the documentation of the function/method that you're calling and ensure that you're using the right data types.

Comment: You say *Insert the element in the linked list at the particular index* for `hashTable[index].push_back(s);` but `hashTable` is just an array.  There is no `push_back` member for arrays.

Comment: [`std::string::push_back`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/push_back) takes a char as parameter not another string

Comment: Where is this linked-list your code comments mention? I only see an array of strings?

Comment: I think you're mixing up `char` and `std::string` here. The type of `hashTable[index][i]` is `char`, not `std::string`.

Comment: @NathanOliver `hashTable[index]` is not an array, though. It's a `std::string`. The issue is that they are mis-using `push_back()`, not trying to call it on a type that doesn't support it.

Comment: So whats the alternative for push_back()?

Comment: Found It!! I need to include vector as mentioned by @Yasir khan and then when I tried to insert the words from txt file into Hash Table I typed it as ((  i=0;i<23;i++ )) which is clear and silly mistake. my bad   :-! ).  Once again thanks for the support everyone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the correct version of your program. Your hashtable is supposed to be a collection of strings and since you are using indexing in the search function, using an STL vector for hashtable should do the trick.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstring>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>

std::vector<std::string> hashTable[27];
int hashTableSize = 27;
#define MAX_LEN 27
using namespace std;


int hashFunc(std::string s)
{
    // A simple hashing, no collision handled
    int sum=0,index=0;
    for(std::string::size_type i=0; i < s.length(); i++)
    {
        sum += s[i];
    }
    index = sum % MAX_LEN;
    return index;
}

void insert(std::string s)
{
    // Compute the index using Hash Function
    int index = hashFunc(s);
    // Insert the element in the linked list at the particular index
    hashTable[index].push_back(s);
    }

void search(string s)
{
    //Compute the index by using the hash function
    int index = hashFunc(s);
    //Search the linked list at that specific index
    for(int i = 0;i < hashTable[index].size();i++)
    {
        if(hashTable[index][i] == s)
        {
            cout << s << " is found!" << endl;
            return;
        }
    }
    cout << s << " is not found!" << endl;
}

int main(){
    //opening text file
    std::ifstream inFile;
    inFile.open("un.txt");

    // If text file doesnot exist or not included in root folder.
    if(inFile.fail()) {

        std::cerr << "Error opening file"<< std::endl ;

        exit(1);
    }

    //if text file exists.
    std::string wordsinfile;
    std::vector<std::string> words;
    std::string str;


    // writing words from text file into Array.
    while( inFile >> wordsinfile) {
        words.push_back(std::move(wordsinfile));
    }

    std::cout << "Total words read: " << words.size() << std::endl;

    for (int i = 0;i < words.size(); i++){
        std::cout << words[i] << std::endl;
    }


    for(int i=0; i < words.size(); i++) {
        insert(words[i]);
    }


    int choice;
    string z;
    string y;
    while(1) {

        cout << "Enter choice. 1) Insert\n 2) Search\n 3) Exit\n";
        cin >> choice;
        switch (choice) {
            case 1:
                cin>>y;
                insert(y);
                break;
            case 2:

                cin>>z;
                search(z);
                break;
            case 3:
                exit(0);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the input. But, the words after 27 words are not being inserted into hash table. Can you please look and tell why and find a solution?

Comment: I have updated the code, now instead of saving only 24 words read from the file, it will insert all the words read from the file into the hash table.

Comment: Yes,but it's not showing them when I use search function.Please do run the code and search for any word after 27th word it's not showing up.

Comment: Strange, it is working fine for me and I can search more than 30 words. Can you share your text file with me? I guess it has something to do with the format of the data in the file.

Comment: Sure. Please do share your text file as well.

Comment: Or else here is the way I used a text file. Each line contains one word and no extra spaces after that. Then I have 38 different words in 38 lines in txt file. So, please do correct me if there is any mistake    :-)                                                    By the way which IDE do you use?  I use CLion of JetBrains. What do you think of it?

Comment: My bad! It's working very well. Thank you very much. All this time I have small problem in including the text file to resources of Clion IDE it made this mess. Again thnak you very much!!